# how to move tableView Cells when UITextField Shwoing up

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

im trying to solve this issue .

when i try to add a comment the view it dosn't move up .

onley the text field show up in the cell .

what i need to fugire out how to move the cell when i send a comment .

https://i.ibb.co/nCFQBwr/Screen-Shot-2019-04-30-at-2-00-37-AM.png

```
 @IBOutlet weak var stack: UIStackView!
let postID = "LdZwtugqxb8-Z6SfduF"
@IBOutlet weak var buttomCnstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var userContentArray = [UserModel]()
var commentContinerArray = [CommentModel]()
@IBOutlet weak var commentTextFieldOutLet: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewOutLet: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableViewOutLet.dataSource = self
    tableViewOutLet.rowHeight = 171.5
    tableViewOutLet.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    ObserveCommentFromPostID()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillshow), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillshow (notification : NSNotification ) {

    let kayBoard = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

        self.buttomCnstraint.constant = kayBoard!.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide (notification : NSNotification) {


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.buttomCnstraint.constant = 0

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what are you trying to achieve... Is the comment view supposed to be part of the cell? It doesn't seem to be based on your code.

Comment: just use   pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'  it will  works on all View  and hierarchy of Views.

Comment: my issue was when user try to comment liks insta app the comment view should animated up . so i figure it out by adding the indexPath.count  .